# Web scraping, I'm trying to extract data from website in the form of list , for some reason its empty list [] and there is no error

Tags: python

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

date = input("Which year do you want to travel to? Type the date in this format YYYY-MM-DD: ")

response = requests.get("https://www.billboard.com/charts/hot-100/" + date)

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
song_names_spans = soup.find_all("span", class_="chart-element__information__song")
song_names = [song.getText() for song in song_names_spans]
print(song_names)
```

Web scraping, I'm trying to extract data from a website  in the form of list, for some reason its empty list [] and there is no error

**output**
Which year do you want to travel to? Type the date in this format YYYY-MM-DD: 12-12-2012
[]

Comment: The date you entered is not in the proper format. You entered `12-12-2012` not `2012-12-12`

Comment: thanks and sorry for this I didn't see

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct but the way you entered the date is wrong.
It's `YYYY-MM-DD` So you have to enter the date as for example, `2020-10-11`

Comment: yeah thanks, I don't know why cant I see that small thing 
I'm blind to see my own error